# How to programatically create MANY nested lists in R and access them?

Tags: r, recursion

I am trying to implement another Hierarchical Clustering algorithm and I thought that I can use MANY nested lists.
This is my start list

```
mdata <- list(node = list(n1 = list(cluster = c(1,2,3), sth = "junk")))
```

I can use lapply to access first node and produce this:

```
mdata_itr1 <- lapply(mdata$node, function(x){
node <- list(node = list(n1 = list(cluster = c(3,2,1), sth = "anything",
                         n2 = list(cluster = c(2,3,1), sth = "anything"))))
x <- append(x, node)})
```

It should be like a binary tree. Each node consists of two nodes (n1, n2) with information like cluster, sth, then another node. I want to have as many nodes as I want.
I was trying to play with a recursive function, but honestly, it's my first time with them. I kinda get the concept, but for such a task, it is currently getting way above my head.

```
addNode <- function(mdata, itr = 3){
out <- lapply(mdata$node, function(x, itr){
    node <- list(node = list(n1 = list(cluster = paste0("I was here. Thx. ", itr), sth = "junk"),
                             n2 = list(cluster = paste0("I was here too ", itr), sth = "junk")))
    x <- append(x, node)
    itr = itr - 1
    if(itr==0){
        return(x)
    }else{
        x <- append(x, addNode(x, itr))
    }
}, itr = itr)
return(out)}
```

It is just one of many attempts. I was trying to play with `e1 <- environment()` and `e1$mdata <- gdata::update.list(object = get("mdata", e1), new = node)`. But as before, it was too much for me.

Do you have any ideas? Or is there a better way to store this amount of information in a tree-like format? I can do all this just by writing files to the disk in an ordered manner, but I am looking for a better solution. I am kindly asking for any advice!

I am adding the expected result, as output from `dput()`

```
list(node = list(n1 = list(cluster = c(1, 2, 3), other_info = "other", 
node = list(n1 = list(cluster = c(1, 2, 3), other_info = "other"), 
    n2 = list(cluster = c(1, 2, 3), other_info = "other"))), 
n2 = list(cluster = c(1, 2, 3), other_info = "other", node = list(
    n1 = list(cluster = c(1, 2, 3), other_info = "other"), 
    n2 = list(cluster = c(1, 2, 3), other_info = "other")))))
```

Comment: In your `addNode()` function, where does `mother$node` come from? Should it instead be `mdata` or `mdata$node`? What exactly is supposed to be passed to `mdata`?

Comment: It would also be helpful if you could provide an example of what you expect the final object to look like.

Comment: Thank you for pointing those out! It should be mdata all along. I have also added an example of the expected final object.

Comment: Have you looked at [{data.tree}](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.tree/vignettes/data.tree.html)? More generally, I feel like [R6 classes](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/r6.html) may be helpful for this task.

Comment: No, thank you. I will give it a try!